# Bash - rename file

Tags: regex, bash

I need bash script to handle those two files:

```
GAMES_12345678_123456_001.xml
GAMES_01234567_012346_CFG.xml
```

I would like to rename first one:

```
 GAMES_12345678_123456_001.xml
```

to:

```
games.xml
```

The second file:

```
GAMES_01234567_012346_CFG.xml
```

I want just to remove.

Here is the thing that those numbers that are in middle "GAMES_12345678_123456_001.xml"  are random so I need to make some kind of regex (maybe?) within bash script to match these names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there are no other GAMES files in the directory, you can simply

```
rm GAMES_*_CFG.xml
mv GAMES_*.xml games.xml
```

If there are more files involved, please describe how to select the two files to remove and delete.

Comment: actualy I got another question... how to use "mv GAMES_*.xml games.xml" when there are serval files with such type of name, I just want to remove all and only rename the lastest?

Comment: @DanielFukuda: you can sort the files by age and omit the first one: `ls -t GAMES_*.xml | tail -n+2`. Then just remove them.  This can be tricky if the filenames contain special characters, in which case I would probably switch to Perl.